# How to add multiple input values to store in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Trying to add to a store on click from an input.  There would be multiple inputs with different parts of an objects info. How can I grab in input data from a method?

In this case, I'm working with packets via a store

```
<input label="Packet Name" v-model="packets.name"  required><br>
<input label="Packet Name" v-model="packets.folder"  required><br>
<button @click="addPacket">Add</button>
```

On the addPacket call how do I get the input data?

Full jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tga9sfcm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I added two data props to the app: name and folder.
- Changed v-model binding to this two props.
- Dispatched an action on button click.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tga9sfcm/6/)

Also, note that you dispatch Actions and commit Mutations. You had your action dispatching a mutation: `store.dispatch('ADD_PACKET', packet)`